# Is the Backus-Naur Form a type 2 grammar? If So why?

Tags: formal-grammars, discrete-mathematics

I understand that the Backus-Naur Form is utilized to assess and specify type 2 grammar, but is it in itself a form of type 2 grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backus-Naur Form is a *conventional notation* for writing Context-Free Grammars.

Its usefulness comes from the need to distinguish the character encoding standards that are used to write texts in various computer languages from the higher-order alphabets of terminal and non-terminal symbols (corresponding to lexical units and syntactical variables, respectively) used in the definition of grammars.

The very idea of using CFGs to define the syntax of high-level programming languages was remarkably precocius, which is another reason why the work of John Backus and Peter Naur was so appreciated at the time.